# TensorFlow: Is there a way to check if the model training is using XLA compilation?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have installed TF from source and enabled XLA JIT compilation. When I run my training code in a session, it shows the following messages:

```
"XLA service 0x62bb180 executing computations on platform Host" and
"XLA service 0x62a43b0 executing computations on platform CUDA"
```

Does this mean that my training is with the `XLA_GPU` device? Because when I tried to explicitly wrap my session with `tf.device("/device:XLA_GPU:0")`, there is seemingly no performance gains at all (the training speed is still the same). And from the documentation I read, it seems that wrapping the session with `tf.device` is one of the ways to activate XLA JIT.

Is there a way to verify whether I am using XLA JIT in my training?